# Fade slideshow single image

Tags: html, css, css-animations, slideshow, keyframe

I have a fading slideshow on my homepage that cycles through 4 images. On the inside pages, I'm just going to feature one image, but I'd like it to perform it's initial animation and then stop. The particular slideshow I am using uses CSS keyframes, but if I remove the CSS keyframes or the animate CSS, then the page just sits there and does nothing when it loads. The animate CSS is set to infinite, which I know is part of it because it's infinitely cycling through but what I am trying to do is keep the same consistency on the inside pages, with just one image it needs the initial animation, but after the initial animation and the image loads, the slideshow should stop. Right now, it seems to walk through everything, so with the CSS keyframes it loads my image, then it's blank for a while and will eventually show the image again. I know that's how it's designed to work, I just don't know how to tweak it to work with just a single image without it cycling through those CSS keyframes like it does. Even if the CSS is entirely different, that's fine because it'll be on a completely different page :-)

HTML:

```
<div class="slide">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575932150875-d31ebc835f67?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80)"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608500567505-269fa4192c58?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1704&q=80)"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477936821694-ec4233a9a1a0?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1620&q=80)"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485735662814-c4f66e49dbae?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80)"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide {
    background: #fff;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.slide > div {
    animation: slide 16s infinite;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.slide > div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.slide > div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 8s;
}

.slide > div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 12s;
}

@keyframes slide {
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    40% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nd81hzuc/ that has four images :-)

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the animation for only one image. First, remove the divs you don't wish to show. Then, you need to replace `infinite` for `forwards 1`. Finally adjust your @keyframes, set "opacity" and "transform" to 100% and the value to how you wish the image to stay.

```css
  .slide {
  background: #fff;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide>div {
  animation: slide 10s forwards 1; /* Play animation only once */
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes slide {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575932150875-d31ebc835f67?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this one, for sure!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this property `animation-iteration-count: 1;` to decide how many times your animation will run . You can use the single image in `<div class="slide">` so that only 1 image is loop through `@keyframes` and this for ease in animation :

```
@keyframes slide {
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    40% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: opacity(1);
    }
}
```

Like demo in below snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      /*Shorthand property of animation ~ animation: example 4s 1;*/
    }
    
    @keyframes example {
      10% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      30% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      40% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
      }
      60% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      100% {
        transform: opacity(1);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I like both solutions!! Thank you for the help, I chose the other one because it was closest to my original code :-) just wanted you to know I appreciate the time you took to lend a hand!

Comment: Anytime as community is for helping each other but if you like answers than you can upvote them , just saying ; )

Comment: Absolutely, totally agree!

Answer (score 0):

You can give the single img basically the same keyframes with a slight tweak - get it to stay at opacity: 1 and with animation-fill-mode set to forwards.

```html
<style>
/* Reset */
  
  html,
  body,
  div,
  span,
  applet,
  object,
  iframe,
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6,
  p,
  blockquote,
  pre,
  a,
  abbr,
  acronym,
  address,
  big,
  cite,
  code,
  del,
  dfn,
  em,
  font,
  img,
  ins,
  kbd,
  q,
  s,
  samp,
  small,
  strike,
  strong,
  sub,
  sup,
  tt,
  var,
  dl,
  dt,
  dd,
  ol,
  ul,
  li,
  fieldset,
  form,
  label,
  legend,
  table,
  caption,
  tbody,
  tfoot,
  thead,
  tr,
  th,
  td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  /* remember to define focus styles! */
  
  :focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;
  }
  
  ol,
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
  
  table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  
  caption,
  th,
  td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  blockquote:before,
  blockquote:after,
  q:before,
  q:after {
    content: "";
  }
  
  blockquote,
  q {
    quotes: "" "";
  }
  /* Slides */
  
  .slide {
    background: #fff;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .slide>div {
    animation: slidestay 16s 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  @keyframes slidestay {
    10% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    30% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    40% {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
</style>
<div class="slide">
  <div style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575932150875-d31ebc835f67?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I liked this solution too, just figured I'd choose the simplest answer :-) Thanks for sharing!